# Ninject - getting binding of an interface

Tags: ninject

I have a binding of an interface to a concrete class thus

```
_ninjectKernal.Bind<IAuctionContext>().To<AuctionContext>()
```

What I want to do in my code is get the concrete class for the interface `IAuctionContext`.  So I want to do something like this

IAuctionContext context = .GetBinding();

Where `context` will be of type `AuctionContext`.

Is this possible.  I've done similar stuff with StructureMap in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// get access to the "container"
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(.....);

// use kernel, as you would any other container
var context = kernel.Get<IAuctionContext>();
```

*Note - If you are using dependency injection you should shy away from calling `Get( ... )` in   "Kernel" (or `Container.GetInstance( ... )` in StructureMap) directly.*

Comment: I agree with your last point.  There is some technical debt that needs to be dealt with on this project.